# Переопределение дефолтного template во vuetify v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify

```js
<template>
  <ExpansionPanel
        title="Ф-402 Ведомость электропотребления"
        class="pa-0"
    >
    <div class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between">
      <div class="d-flex align-center">
        <div>Выберите период</div>

                <div class="mx-8">
                    <month-picker
                        v-model="to"
                        :min="from"
                        :max="max"
                        placeholder="мм.гггг"
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <v-btn color="primary">Показать</v-btn>
        </div>

    <v-data-table
      disable-sort
      :headers="headers"
      :items="tableData"
      hide-default-footer
    >

            <template
                v-slot:item.counterNumber="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.counterNumber }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.counterNumber }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>
            <template
                v-slot:item.meterOnPeriodBeginning="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.meterOnPeriodBeginning }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.meterOnPeriodBeginning }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.meterOnPeriodEnding="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.meterOnPeriodEnding }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.meterOnPeriodEnding }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.meterDiff="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.meterDiff }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.meterDiff }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.designFactor="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.designFactor }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.designFactor }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.expenseWithPU="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.expenseWithPU }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.expenseWithPU }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.expenseWithoutPU="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.expenseWithoutPU }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.expenseWithoutPU }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

    </v-data-table>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-data-table
            class="mt-4"
            disable-pagination
            disable-sort
            :headers="headersPart2"
            :items="tableData"
            hide-default-footer
        >
            <template
                v-slot:item.additionalExpense="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.additionalExpense }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.additionalExpense }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.SPM="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.SPM }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.SPM }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.loss="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.loss }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.loss }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.recalculation="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.recalculation }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.recalculation }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.consumption="{ item }"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                >
                    <b>{{ item.consumption }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.consumption }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>

            <template
                v-slot:item.subscribers="{ item }"
                v-for="c in 3"
            >
                <div
                    class="d-flex flex-column"
                    :key="c"
                >
                    {{c}}
                    <b>{{ item.subscribers }}</b>
                    <span>{{ item.subscribers }}</span>
                </div>
            </template>
        </v-data-table>
  </ExpansionPanel>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Mixins, Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import ExpansionPanel from "../ui/ExpansionPanel.vue";
import { ContractIdValidatorMixin } from "@/mixins/ContractIdValidatorMixin";
import MonthPicker from "@/components/ui/MonthPicker.vue";

@Component({
  components: {
    ExpansionPanel,
        MonthPicker,
  },
})

export default class ElectricityReport extends Mixins(ContractIdValidatorMixin) {

    from = "";
    to = "";
    max = "";
    headers =
             [
                { text: 'Код ТУ', value: 'code' },
                { text: 'Наименование ТУ', value: 'name' },
                { text: 'Номер счетчика/Тарифная зона', value: 'counterNumber' },
                { text: 'Показания на начало периода', value: 'meterOnPeriodBeginning' },
                { text: 'Показания на конец периода', value: 'meterOnPeriodEnding' },
                { text: 'Разность показаний', value: 'meterDiff' },
                { text: 'Расч. коэф.', value: 'designFactor' },
                { text: 'Расход по ПУ, кВт.ч', value: 'expenseWithPU' },
                { text: 'Расход без ПУ, кВт.ч', value: 'expenseWithoutPU' },
            ]

        headersPart2 =
             [
                { text: 'Код ТУ', value: 'code' },
                { text: 'Наименование ТУ', value: 'name' },
                { text: 'Доп. расход, кВт.ч', value: 'additionalExpense' },
                { text: 'СМП, кВт.ч', value: 'SPM' },
                { text: 'Потери, кВт.ч', value: 'loss' },
                { text: 'Субабоненты, кВт.ч', value: 'subscribers' },
                { text: 'Перерасчет, кВт.ч', value: 'recalculation' },
                { text: 'Потребление, кВт.ч', value: 'consumption' },
            ]

    tableData = [
                {
                    code: 953510076,
                    name: "ПС-102 Ф-11",
                    counterNumber: "01334316",
                    meterOnPeriodBeginning: "00353.287",
                    meterOnPeriodEnding: "00392.530",
                    meterDiff: "39.243",
                    designFactor: "20000",
                    expenseWithPU: "784 860",
                    expenseWithoutPU: "",
                    additionalExpense: "",
                    SPM: "",
                    loss: "",
                    subscribers: "-784 860",
                    recalculation: "-8",
                    consumption: "-8",
                },
        {
            code: 953510077,
            name: "ПС-102 Ф-6",
            counterNumber: "01334319",
            meterOnPeriodBeginning: "00535.348",
            meterOnPeriodEnding: "00579.388",
            meterDiff: "44.040",
            designFactor: "20000",
            expenseWithPU: "880 800",
            expenseWithoutPU: "",
            additionalExpense: "-20",
            SPM: "0",
            loss: "",
            subscribers: "880 790",
            recalculation: "8",
            consumption: "-2",
        },
            ]

}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Необходимо заменить дефолтное отображение в компоненте v-data-table.
В `template` можно передать шаблон для конкретного столбца, но этих столбов 11. Такой код неудобно читаем и, при изменении дизайна, нужно менять в 11 местах.

Код, который имеем сейчас:

```
    <v-data-table
        class="mt-4"
        disable-pagination
        disable-sort
        :headers="headersPart2"
        :items="tableData"
        hide-default-footer
    >
        <template
            v-slot:item.additionalExpense="{ item }"
        >
            <div
                class="d-flex flex-column"
            >
                <b>{{ item.additionalExpense }}</b>
                <span>{{ item.additionalExpense }}</span>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template
            v-slot:item.SPM="{ item }"
        >
            <div
                class="d-flex flex-column"
            >
                <b>{{ item.SPM }}</b>
                <span>{{ item.SPM }}</span>
            </div>
        </template>

        <template
            v-slot:item.SPM="{ item }"
        >
           ...
        </template>
        ...
    </v-data-table>
```

Выглядеть должно так:
[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Также пробовал `v-for`, но таблица рендерится с дефолтным слотом:

```
        <template
            v-for="c in Object.keys(tableData[0])"
            v-slot:item[c]="{ item }"
        >
            <div
                class="d-flex flex-column"
                :key="c"
            >
                <b>{{ item[c] }}</b>
                <span>{{ item[c] }}</span>
            </div>
        </template>
```

Comment: _«но этих столбов 11»_ - `v-for` в помощь.

Comment: @yar85, забыл упомянуть, что `v-for` в этом примере не помог. Таблица рендерится с обычным слотом. Код того, как я использую `v-for` дополнил к вопросу.

Comment: @yar85, сработало при `...\`item.${c}\`...`, т.е. с одинарными обратными кавычками. Так же приложил весь прошлый код, когда проблема была актуальна. Если можете, то оформите свои комментарии как ответ к вопросу, либо я сделаю это немного позже. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Двойные бэктики в комментарии я ставил в попытке экранировать одинарные. Затем заменил на `'item.' + c` чтобы избежать того непонимания, которое фактически произошло... то есть, чуток не успел с правкой :) А как у тебя получилось в последнем комментарии ` заэкранировать? Помню, два года назад я тут познал это тайное искусство, но впоследствии оно было утеряно из памяти.

Comment: @yar85, обратным слешем ( \ ) перед бэктиком

Comment: Самый очевидный вариант, а я не догадался его попробовать)) Спасибо :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы в шаблоне избежать дублирования одинаковой разметки для нескольких слотов, можно применить директиву `v-for`.

Небольшая сложность в том, что компонент `v-data-table` использует динамические имена слотов столбцов таблицы, в формате `header.<name>` и `item.<name>` - где *<name>* является именем свойства объекта данных (элемента `items`).
Проблема попадания контента в слот по-умолчанию, возникала в коде вопроса только из-за передачи в качестве имени слота значения из объекта данных, вместо ожидаемого компонентом "пути" к свойству.
В шаблоне нам необходимо использовать *вычисленное* имя каждого слота участвующего в переборе:

```
<template v-for="prop in itemProps"
  v-slot:[`item.${prop}`]="{ item }"
>
  <div class="d-flex flex-column" :key="prop">
    <b>{{ item[prop] }}</b>
    <span>{{ item[prop] }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Массив с именами свойств для перебора (названный `itemProps` в примере выше) может быть задан литералом, либо может вычисляться из конфигурации заголовков таблицы (представим что в компоненте этот конфиг представлен массивом `headers`):

```
computed: {
  itemProps() {
    return this.headers.map(header => header.value);
  },
  // ...
},
```

---

Демо на основе [примера из справки Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item) - здесь, для демонстрации цикла по слотам через `v-for`, оборачиваются в chip значения *всех* столбцов (а не только второго, как в оригинале):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        { name: 'Ice cream sandwich', calories: 237, fat: 9.0, carbs: 37, protein: 4.3, iron: '1%' },
        { name: 'Eclair', calories: 262, fat: 16.0, carbs: 23, protein: 6.0, iron: '7%' },
        { name: 'Cupcake', calories: 305, fat: 3.7, carbs: 67, protein: 4.3, iron: '8%' },
        { name: 'Gingerbread', calories: 356, fat: 16.0, carbs: 49, protein: 3.9, iron: '16%' },
        { name: 'Jelly bean', calories: 375, fat: 0.0, carbs: 94, protein: 0.0, iron: '0%' },
        { name: 'Lollipop', calories: 392, fat: 0.2, carbs: 98, protein: 0, iron: '2%' },
        { name: 'Honeycomb', calories: 408, fat: 3.2, carbs: 87, protein: 6.5, iron: '45%' },
        { name: 'Donut', calories: 452, fat: 25.0, carbs: 51, protein: 4.9, iron: '22%' },
        { name: 'KitKat', calories: 518, fat: 26.0, carbs: 65, protein: 7, iron: '6%' },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    itemProps() {
      return this.headers.map(header => header.value);
    },
  },
  methods: {
    getColor (calories) {
      if (calories > 400) return 'red'
      else if (calories > 200) return 'orange'
      else return 'green'
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" class="elevation-1">
      <template v-for="prop in itemProps"
        v-slot:[`item.${prop}`]="{ item }"
      >
        <v-chip dark :key="prop" :color="getColor(item.calories)">
          {{ item[prop] }}
        </v-chip>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```